# Did the Easterlings have fortifications or kingdoms like the west did?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth

During the fourth age Aragorn and his son were said to have finally subdued the easterlings and allowed them to return to their great empire. So my question is did the Easterlings have kingdoms and fortifications as great as the west did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tolkien wrote so little about the East that we honestly don't know.

One thing we do know is that the Easterlings were **not** a single people and **not** a single culture.  For example, from Appendix A:

> The Wainriders were a people, or a confederacy of many peoples, that came from the East; but they were stronger and better armed than any that had appeared before.

So we therefore can't make this kind of blanket statement about them.  In other words: some Easterling cultures may have had such kingdoms, but other Easterling cultures may not.

Comment: Is it bad that im asking so many questions?

Comment: I don't think so, your questions are interesting. And we have Darth Satan here who is encyclopedic and that is also interesting...

Comment: @user31546 - there's no such thing as too many good questions and I'm happy to answer where I can.

Comment: @user31546 - it's probably bad if you (a) hit a question limit or (b) have questions that are primarily downvoted or 0-upvote. It seems that neither of these apply to you, so you're probably fine